# Turning screen on and off in Android

Tags: android, printing, boolean, android-lifecycle

I am having a bit of trouble with regards to the Android code I am trying to produce. What I am trying to do is simply print out a 1 if the user wants to unlock their phone, and when the program first starts, and a 0 when the user presses the screen lock to lock their phone. I thought this had to do with the Android lifecycle so I tried using onPause and onResume, but my program only prints out 0's, never 1's. The logTime method simply prints out the 1 or a 0, and the onCreate method in the MainActivity calls onResume() once. Here is my code:

MainActivity:

```
protected void onPause(){
    if(ScreenReceiver.screenOn){
        logTime(ScreenReceiver.screenOn); 
 super.onPause();
}

protected void onResume()
  if(!ScreenReceiver.screenOn){
    logTime(!ScreenReceiver.screenOn);
super.onResume();
}
```

Screen Receiver:

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
public static boolean screenOn;


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
        screenOn = false;
    }
    else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
        screenOn = true;
    }

}
```

}

I'm not sure why it only prints out 0's. Might anyone know why? Thanks!

Comment: `logTime(!ScreenReceiver.screenOn)` should be just `logTime(ScreenReceiver.screenOn);` no `!`

Comment: @A--C Hm okay. I'm having some trouble now--whenever I resume my application, I never am able to log the 1. When I unlock the screen, nothing is printed , but when I lock the screen, it prints out the 0. Might you know why?

Comment: Where do you register/unregister the Receiver? What you have (aside from calling `logTime()` with basically the same parameter) looks correct.

Comment: I simply registered it in the onCreate part of my MainActivity. This is what I have down:

  IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
  filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
  BroadcastReceiver receiver = new ScreenReceiver();
  registerReceiver(receiver, filter);

Comment: I see what you mean. There is a delay between the actual receiving, so you get odd printouts.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it then? I noticed that screenOn never evaluates to be false which is why it never goes into the onResume method... is there a reason for that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25028/discussion-between-user200081-and-a-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a delay between your Activity's `onPause()` and the actual Broadcast being received, so usually you can get "odd" (wrong) readings since the variable change hasn't happened. This receiver needs to be dynamically registered, and you also want it to receive even when the screen is off and turns back on. Usually, Receivers are unregistered in onPause() to avoid leaking, but here, we're going to use `onDestroy()` since that's the last method call we can use. For simplicity, I made the `BroadcastReceiver` right in the Activity and called `logTime()` outright.

Sample Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  BroadcastReceiver receiver;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON); 
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF); 
    receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){

      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        if(arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
          logTime(false);
        }
        else if(arg1.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
          logTime(true);
        }
      } 
    }; 
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDestroy()
  {
    try{
      unregisterReceiver (receiver);
    }
    catch (NullPointerException e){  
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalStateException e1){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
  }


  public void logTime (boolean screen)
  {
    Time now = new Time();
    now.setToNow();

    String lsNow = now.format("%m-%d-%Y %I:%M:%S");
    TextView myText = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.myText);
    myText.append (" " + lsNow + (screen ? "0" : "1"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick Question--what is receiver supposed to be? What type of variable is it?

Comment: @user200081 `BroadcastReceiver receiver;` it's just a BroadcastReceiver. I'd say instead of merging my sample with your code, just set the content view to the `layout` xml you're using in your Activity to check if my sample works. As you can see, I got rid of `onPause()/onResume()` since they aren't needed anymore.

Comment: sorry to bother you so much but I want to log a 1 when the application first starts. I tried doing a flag in the beginning of the onCreateMethod (eg if test == 0) then output a 1, and increment test to 1 so that it never happens again. However, my Activity keeps crashing because of that. Any ideas on why and how to do this?

Comment: @user200081 based on what you've said I don't know why. As for how to do it, either a static `int`, or use `SharedPreferences` so the value persists (`onCreate()` is called on orientation changes, and under normal lifecycle events, the Activity is destroyed then recreated for this). However, if you can't figure this out yourself, your best bet is to ask another question, including your code to date and the *full* stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems right based on your code, it should always print 0...

When the screen is turned off, `screenOn` is set to `false`, your Activity's `onPause` is called, it prints 0.

When your application is running and `onResume` is called, `screenOn` would be `true` (whether the screen was just turned on or not), there, you log the opposite of `screenOn`, so would be 0 again...